# Java error message "Cannot be resolved to a variable"?

Tags: java

ok so I'm kinda new to java and I'm trying to make a class which will be able to ask the user to input a 12 digit long upc code, check to make sure its a valid code, and then display if it is or not. I've got quite a few errors with the current program that I have and I can't seem to figure it out. This is the code that I have so far:

```
public class Upc {
    private long upc;

    public Upc(long upcs) {
        upc = upcs;
    }

    public long getUpc() {

        int m = (n2 + n4 + n6 + n8 + n10);
        long n = (n1 + n3 + n5 + n7 + n9 + n11);
        long r = (10 - (m + 3 * n) % 10);

        long n12 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n11 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n10 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n9 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n8 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n7 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n6 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n5 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n4 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n3 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n2 = (int) (upc % 10);
        upc /= 10;
        long n1 = (int) (upc % 10);

        if (r == n12) {
            return (upc + " is a feasible UPC code");
        } else {
            return (upc + " is an invalid UPC code");
        }
    }
}
```

and my errors are as follows:

```
13 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 10]
Error: n2 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 10]
Error: n4 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 10]
Error: n6 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 10]
Error: n8 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 10]
Error: n10 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 11]
Error: n1 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 11]
Error: n3 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 11]
Error: n5 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 11]
Error: n7 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 11]
Error: n9 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 11]
Error: n11 cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 39]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to long
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 42]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to long
```

I feel like fixing one or two things will eliminate alot of this, can anyone help me?

Comment: If I might make a suggestion to someone starting out in Java... If you aren't already, try developing with a proper IDE (I'd recommend [Eclipse](www.eclipse.org) but there are other good free options). This will help with all sorts of things, from giving suggestions for fixing errors to automatically formatting code to automatically compiling, etc. I would also recommend naming your variables/methods/classes meaningfully (ok, kind of hard when they're mathematical, but still) and learning to refactor repetitious code where possible (once and only once rule). Good luck and keep at it! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this variable define after

```
long n12 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n11 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n10 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n9 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n8 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n7 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n6 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n5 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n4 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n3 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n2 = (int) (upc%10);
upc /= 10;
long n1 = (int) (upc%10);



int m = (n2 + n4 + n6 + n8 + n10);
long n = (n1 + n3 + n5 + n7 + n9 + n11);
long r = (10-(m+3*n)%10);
```

you'r using that variable which was not been defined and after using you define that variables

Edit : for if

As you define you method with the return value as long time and you return the String value, see the return value

```
return (upc + " is a feasible UPC code");
```

you need to change the return type either in method or as return time like if you want to return this then you method signature looks like this

```
public long getUpc(){
  // and return will work
  return (upc + " is a feasible UPC code"); 
}
```

but if you want to only numeric value then do not change it's method signature just return the upc like this

```
return upc;
```

Comment: oh wow lol thanks. Ok so I did that and now I only have two errors which are with the if statement at the end. I think I did the if statement wrong somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: the error I'm getting on the if statement at the end says       "File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 39]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to long
File: C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Upc.java  [line: 42]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to long"

Answer (score 3):

This is because you haven't declared those variables before you use them on this these lines:

```
int m = (n2 + n4 + n6 + n8 + n10);
long n = (n1 + n3 + n5 + n7 + n9 + n11);
```

You declared them ***after***...

Based on what I think you're trying to do, you need to move these three lines to ***after*** that large chunk of division/modulus code:

```
int m = (n2 + n4 + n6 + n8 + n10);
long n = (n1 + n3 + n5 + n7 + n9 + n11);
long r = (10-(m+3*n)%10);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using variables before telling the compiler what are they. First you should Declare Them and then use them.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, for the 11 first errors you have to declare first of all the variables, then you can use them.

For the last 2 errors: you declared the getUpc() method as a LONG one, os it's expect to be returning a LONG type return; instead, you're returning a String.
Change the method declaration or change the return type and it should work.